# How to implement a continuous world based on FlxTilemap

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

`FlxTilemap` is a very handy implementation of a tilemap in the HaxeFlixel library. Currently I have working code taking maps generated with the Ogmo map editor and loaded with `FlxOgmoLoader` (also from the HaxeFlixel library) into a `FlxTilemap`. I would like to have a world composed of multiple tile maps that are seamlessly displayed as the player moves.

It seems this is not supported by the library. Could someone provide ideas or references on how to implement this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not perfect, you could design your tilemaps in a way they connect with each other, and keep loading them (filtering as you need) while the player moves, like

```
if (player.x > currentTilemap.width) {
    tilemapGroup.add(new FlxTilemap(currentTilemap.x + currentTilemap.width, currentTilemap.y);
}
```

Also, to keep it from running out of memory, use `isOnScreen()` to make the tilemaps invisible and deactived if they aren't on camera.